# how to remove special characters in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This a sample of the data I am working with:

```
Reviews  Size     Installs  Type     Price      Content Rating  
0     159   19M      10,000+  paid     $9.99       Everyone   
1     967   14M     500,000+  paid     $0.99       Everyone   
2   87510  8.7M   5,000,000+  paid     $1.9        Everyone   
3  215644   25M  50,000,000+  paid     $7.50       Teen   
4     967  2.8M     100,000+  Free     0            Everyone
```

I want sort the dataframe by the price but as the datatypes of the values in the "Price" column are string, I can't sort the dataframe and can't cast the values either because of the character "$". Is there a way to do remove it or sort the dataframe successfully without removing "$"?

I tried the following just to see if I could sort the target column:

```
 df = pd.read_csv('googleplaystore.csv')
 category = df['Price'].tolist()
 c = list(set(category))
 print (sorted(c))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

```
df['Price'] = df.Price.str.replace('$','')
df.sort_values('Price')
```

Of if you don't want to remove the char `$` you could use

```
df = df.iloc[df.Price.str.replace('$','').astype(float).sort_values().index,:]
df.reset_index(drop=True) # To reset index
```

But you should convert the column to numeric to be able to do numeric operations on your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it all in one chain:

```
(df.assign(content = df.Content.str.replace("$", ""))
   .sort_values("content", ascending=False)
   .drop("content", 1)
)
   Reviews    Size Installs         Type Price Content    Rating
0        0     159      19M      10,000+  paid   $9.99  Everyone
3        3  215644      25M  50,000,000+  paid   $7.50      Teen
2        2   87510     8.7M   5,000,000+  paid    $1.9  Everyone
1        1     967      14M     500,000+  paid   $0.99  Everyone
4        4     967     2.8M     100,000+  Free       0  Everyone
```